# Changing textView color based on positive/negative number through xml

Tags: android, textview

I want to know whether there is any option to describe textview color based it is positive or negative number through xml only.
if not possible through xml then how can i do it in java as my code make number go positive to negative and viceversa many time and color remain as of starting of App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this: (with myTV being your `TextView`)

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(myTV.getText());
if(number<0){
     myTV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.negativeColor));
}
else{
     myTV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.positiveColor));
}
```

There is no way to do this in XML...

Comment: I already applied that code but i applied at oncreate method. but it's color not changing after my code process data. I dont want to add this code at all location where data changes so is there any way where just placing code at one place do the trick

Comment: AFAIK no easy way. You could create a custom TextView. This would be the  only way I could imagine.

Comment: is there any way to do same in xml